# Recommendations for developing Sweave documents

Tags: emacs, r, latex, sweave, ess

I'm looking to streamline my [Sweave](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweave) document creation, and I'd like to hear about people's current setups.  I feel like the holy grail goes something like this:

- Editing Rnw code on one half of the
  screen
- Single keybinding compiles
  Sweave document and runs pdflatex
- View PDF
  on the other half of the screen; once
  compiled, PDF is refreshed and centered around the portion of the document you're editing
- If compilation has errors, replace the PDF with the results of the compilation (e.g. latex errors or Sweave errors)

I am guessing/hoping that the solution is part Emacs/ESS combined with some code for the Emacs profile and/or a nice Makefile.  But I would really like to hear about everybody's preferred way of creating Sweave and/or Latex documents.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A few other R users I talked to use a 'one-directory-per-project' setup, and a simple Makefile.  As you suspected, that works well with Emacs/ESS.

I tend to just call a simple shell script `sweave` which I wrote before before 'R CMD Sweave' was added (as I find re-creating or copying the Makefile unappealing, YMMV).  I also use Emacs and an auto-refreshing pdf viewer (like  `okular` or `kpdf`).  Emacs23 can preview pdf files directly too but I have yet to switch my work flow to that.

```
edd@ron:~$ cat bin/sweave
#!/bin/bash -e

function errorexit () {
    echo "Error: $1"
    exit 1
}

function filetest () {
    if [ ! -f $1 ]; then
       errorexit "File $1 not found"
    fi
    return 0
}


if [ "$#" -lt 1 ]; then
    errorexit "Need to specify argument file"
fi


BASENAME=$(basename $1 .Rnw)

RNWFILE=$BASENAME.Rnw
filetest $RNWFILE
echo "library(tools); Sweave(\"$RNWFILE\")" \
      | R --no-save --no-restore --slave

LATEXFILE=$BASENAME.tex
filetest $LATEXFILE && pdflatex $LATEXFILE
```

Answer (score 6):

You can do everything that you suggest there with the StatET plugin for Eclipse.  That's what I use for Sweave development; it understands both latex and R very well, including syntax highlighting, etc.

You can get it here: http://www.walware.de/goto/statet.

Longhow Lam has written a nice guide: http://www.splusbook.com/Rintro/R_Eclipse_StatET.pdf.

http://www.statalgo.com/?p=93

Comment: I agree. Sweave, StatET, and Eclipse work well together. I wrote a post describing one way of configuring Sweave with Eclipse http://bit.ly/adfhZ1

Comment: (splusbook link is broken. however I googled it and the following, seemingly equivalent, alternative, worked for me:  http://www.splusbook.com/RIntro/R_Eclipse_StatET.pdf)

Answer (score 6):

I use [TeXShop](http://www.uoregon.edu/~koch/texshop/) on OS X to produce all of my LaTeX and Sweave reports. For me, a new compilation pipeline is as simple as adding a file, called `Sweave.engine` to `~/Library/TeXShop/Engines/` which contains the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript
args <- commandArgs(T)

fname <- strsplit(args[1],'\\.')[[1]][2]

Sweave(paste(fname,'Rnw',sep='.'))

system(paste('pdflatex',paste(fname,'tex',sep='.')))
```

Sweave is now a selectable method of compiling a document inside TeXShop. I can set it to be the default for a document by adding the following TeX hash-bang to the top of the file:

```
% !TEX TS-program = Sweave
```

Hitting Cmd-T will typeset the document- the pdf automatically pops up in a separate window. TeXShop also incorporates [SyncTeX](http://www.tug.org/texworks/) technology so a Cmd-Click in the Rnw source will highlight the corresponding output in the PDF window and a Cmd-Click in the PDF window will highlight the corresponding input in the Rnw source.

TeXShop is mac-only but a great Qt/poppler-based clone, [TeXworks](http://www.tug.org/texworks/), is available for Linux, Windows and Mac and supports many of the same features-- including TeX hash-bangs and SyncTeX. TeXworks has reached a level of maturity where it is included in version 2.8 of the [MikTeX](http://miktex.org/) package for Windows.

Comment: I like the direct use of Rscript! So many solutions invoke a shell to invoke R... For the record, the `strsplit` and `paste` for handling filename extensions is not necessary - both `Sweave` and `pdflatex` automatically add the extension.

Comment: I think it was necessary at the time I wrote that post as TeX Shop passed the whole filename, `File.Rnw` to the engine. `Sweave` would be fine with it, but `pdflatex` would choke.

Comment: So - you say you have cmd-click between your .Rnw and .pdf files. Did you have to jump through these hoops also: http://cameron.bracken.bz/synctex-with-sweavepgfsweave-in-texshoptexworks

Comment: No I didn't--so the SyncTeX support is probably a bit off. But I tend to write a lot of small Sweave chunks rather than bit ones, so SyncTeX lands me "in the ballpark" where I don't notice the issues associated with not using concordance.

Answer (score 3):

Try [RStudio](http://rstudio.org/).

I have been a fan of [Emacs](http://aquamacs.org/) and [TeXShop](http://pages.uoregon.edu/koch/texshop/obtaining.html) as mentioned in previous answers.

However, Rstudio is starting to win me over. It is a rapidly-improving dedicated IDE for R. Definitely worth checking out.

I still love doing certain R-only development tasks in the [standard R IDE](http://cran.r-project.org/) for mac. But for Sweave documents and some associated R devel at the same time, RStudio wins. It works with virtually zero tweaking. I'm not sure about the PDF-related features in the latter half of the original question.

Answer (score 2):

One thing that has saved me some time is the 'auto-insert' mode in emacs.  I have it set up so that each time I open a new .rnw file, emacs automatically sets up a basic document template and all I need to do is start writing my report.

Update: I've switched away from auto-insert.  Now I use the "template.el" approach.

Answer (score 1):

I use the "one-directory-per-project" and  Makefile approach as well. I also include commands to create output in HTML, which can then be converted to OOo and MS Word, using tth. This is important for me since a lot of my collaborators are MS Office users and are resistant to using the PDF output. I learned a lot about how to do this from Frank Harrell's twiki at Vanderbilt.

Personally I use gvim as my editor of choice and running *make* from there is quite simple, as it is from Emacs.