# R code in Sweave

Tags: r, sweave, literate-programming

I have a scientific paper under review, and a referee asked for my R code to be provided as a Sweave document. I've never heard of Sweave before, do you know what's the better way to do it?

Thanks a lot :-)

Comment: Closely related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379549/recommendations-for-developing-sweave-documents

Comment: It is not 'your R code to be provided as a Sweave document' as Sweave combines LaTeX and R automagically.  So your *paper* becomes an Sweave document.

Comment: So do they mean I should rewrite the whole paper in LaTeX?? Because they specifically write I should provide the R code as a Sweave document.

Comment: Then I hope the referee never reads this post :-D
Because I'm not going to learn LaTeX in one week for him.

Comment: I just want to take this opportunity to salute the referee for this paper - requiring submissions in Sweave is fantastic (for reproducibility, understandability, etc.), even if it's not going to be possible in this case. =)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems a very unusual request in my opinion.  I can understand a referee expecting you to provide reproducible code, but requiring a specific format is over-the-top.  I would respond by providing your code.  Sweave is *not* standard practice for academic journals.

Comment: maybe it should be though (at least when one is using R).

Answer (score 6):

A quick google can lead you to a lot of good resources:

- http://www.stat.uni-muenchen.de/~leisch/Sweave/
- http://www.stat.umn.edu/~charlie/Sweave/
- http://jeromyanglim.blogspot.com/2010/02/getting-started-with-sweave-r-latex.html
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweave

See my answer to this question: [Getting R plots into LaTeX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1890215/getting-r-plots-into-latex)

I personally recommend using either LyX or Eclipse (with StatET and TeXlipse) for this, although there are many options for editing LaTeX out there.

*Edit:*

If your script takes a long time to run, then you can also look at [the cacheSweave package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cacheSweave/index.html).

Comment: Thanks ::-)
Point is that my R code requires days to run, and therefore embed it in Sweave mmm seems somehow not indicated!

Comment: There are caching solutions. Take Shane's advice and Google, this time 'Sweave cache' or something. Also may want to start at rseek.org.

Comment: Thanks guys, I'll try to cache it. Problem is that it was R code that required a month to be run on a cluster :-D

Comment: Then don't re-run it.  Provide them with the Sweave document.  That doesn't mean you need to actually create the paper by running it, so long as the code is the same.  Otherwise, the output of Sweave is LaTeX: just replace the R code sections with their output (e.g. tables of data, charts) by directly importing those things into LaTeX just like you would with a regular paper.