# ESS/AucTeX/Sweave integration

Tags: emacs, r, latex, sweave, ess

I'm using GNU/Linux distro (Arch, if that's relevant), Emacs v23.2.1, ESS v5.9 and AucTeX v11.86.

I want to setup *AucTeX* to recognize **.Rnw** files, so I can run *LaTeX* on **.Rnw** files with `C-c C-c` and get **.dvi** file automatically. I reckon it's quite manageable by editing .emacs file, but I still haven't got a firm grasp on *Elisp*.

Yet another problem is quite annoying - somehow, *LaTeX* is not recognizing `\usepackage{Sweave}` in preambule, so I actually need to copy `Sweave.sty` file (in my case located in `/usr/share/R/texmf/Sweave.sty`) to directory where **.Rnw** file is located (and I'm becoming more frustrated by the fact that this is common bug on Windows platforms!)

My question boils down to two problems:

- how to make *LaTeX* recognize `\usepackage{Sweave}` (without copying `Sweave.sty` to "home" folder each time) [**Edit:** managed to do this; see comment after Dirk's answer]
- how to setup *AucTeX* to compile **.Rnw** files to **.dvi**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's two different questions.

For the first one, my Debian R packages make sure that there is a soft link from the `$RHOME/share/texmf/` directory into the TeX file system tree, e.g. as `/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/R`.

For the second question: dunno. I tend to run Sweave via a small shell script I crafted years ago even though I do all the editing in Emacs.

*Edit, a few months later:* Use ESS, rather than AucTeX.  Then `M-n s` (i.e Alt-n followed by s) runs the Sweave step and `M-n P` runs the LaTeX compilation, with a call to Bibtex if needed.

Comment: Thanks for info on the first one. I managed to do it just by putting `Sweave.sty` file in `/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/Sweave`, hence updating the database from `texconfig`. So that leaves me with #2. Btw, I saw your script on SO, and I'm thinking about binding a bash command to run on .Rnw as a workaround 'till I figure out how to do the AucTeX part.

Answer (score 5):

After brief and efficient Googling, I've found [this link](http://sites.google.com/site/andreaskiermeier/essmaterials), and at first glance, everything seems OK, but pdf file gets garbled after Sweaving... So I tackled this problem another way around: *when in doubt, go **bash***! I've shamelessly stolen error checking function from Dirk's Sweave bash script available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379549/recommendations-for-developing-sweave-documents/1379899#1379899). Basically, this is a workaround: `R CMD Sweave` gets executed on **.Rnw** file, hence *latex* comes in, and *pdflatex* after that...

I'll post a bash script that does the job for me. I must state that I'm not an advanced bash programmer, moreover I'm not even a programmer by vocation, so there's a great chance that this script can be optimized/written properly. Here goes:

```
#!/bin/bash

FILEBASE=${1%.*}
FILEXT=${1##*.}
FILEPATH=${1%/*}

TEXFILE=$FILEBASE.tex
PDFFILE=$FILEBASE.pdf

# errorexit

function errorexit () {
    echo "Error: $1"
    exit 1
}

# check if file exists
if [ ! -f $1 ]; then
    errorexit "File $1 not found!"
else
# check for filename length
    if [ ${#1} -lt 1 ]; then
    errorexit "Need to specify argument file!"
    else
    # if filelength OK, check extension
    if [ $FILEXT != "Rnw" ]; then
        errorexit "You must pass Sweave (.Rnw) file!"
        # finally, run Sweave
    else
        cd $FILEPATH && R CMD Sweave $1
        # latex $TEXFILE
        pdflatex $TEXFILE
        # xdg-open $PDFFILE
    fi
    fi
fi
```

Then save/copy/move this script in any of `echo $PATH` folders (I keep mine in `/usr/bin/`), and make sure that it's named **sweave**, or choose whatever name you like, then put these lines in your **.emacs** file:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c s")
        (lambda ()
          (interactive)
          (shell-command (concat "sweave " buffer-file-name))))
```

Of course, you can change keybinding to suite your needs, and be sure to change **sweave** with script name placed in `/usr/bin/`.

Bare in mind that this is **not** an answer, but a workaround. If you have found a way to deal with AucTeX/ESS/Sweave integration, post it, and I'll give it a checkmark.

Prior to this workaround, I had to do `M-n s` to Sweave, followed by `C-c C-c` which is default keybind in AucTeX for LaTeX file compilation. Produced file is erroneous, so I had to give it a try with bash. It works for me, if you have any suggestions, please let me know.

Kind regards,
aL3xa

**EDIT:**
Inserted `cd $FILEPATH`