# ESS/Auctex/knitr How to cite from bibliography in knitr child document

Tags: r, emacs, knitr, ess, auctex

I am curently using emacs with ESS, Auxtex, R and knitr.
I would like to be able to cite from my bibliography in my child documents.

My master.Rnw looks rougly as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\input{preamble.tex} % with \addbibliography in it

\begin{document}

<<child_1>>=
knit_child("./functions.Rnw")
@

<<child_2>>=
knit_child("./models.Rnw")
@

\end{document}
```

I can knit the document with `Meta-n r` and I can also run `Meta-n P` (as described in the first answer here: [ESS/AucTeX/Sweave integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2940756/ess-auctex-sweave-integration).

Afterwards I can use my bibliography, which I indluded in my `preambel.tex` for citations in my master.Rnw.
If I try to access my bibliography in a child document with `C-c [` I get the error message `"no valid bibliography in this document and no default avalailable"`

Running `Meta-n P` in a child document fails with `"Undefined control sequence \section"`

Any ideas would be really appreciated.

Comment: I found it out myself.  Simply add a default bibliography in your    init.el instead of adding the bibliography in your praembel.tex.  If you do not know how to do this, take a look at the first answer here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54739/reftex-wont-find-my-bib-file-in-local-library-tree Hope this helps someone